# PyCharm reports unused local variable but this variable is used in the local namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I must be missing something as PyCharm is reporting a variable is unused but it is in fact used on the very next line.

Any idea why PyCharm reports this way? Is it a bug or did I do something that needs to be changed?

Code:

```
def start_mass_reassign(self):
    try:
        or_dns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('REDACTED', REDACTED, service_name='REDACTED')
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(user=self.username.get(), password=self.password.get(), dsn=or_dns)
        valid_login = True
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        if 'invalid username/password' in str(e).lower():
            print('Invalid login')
            valid_login = False
        else:
            valid_login = False
            raise

    if valid_login:
        # rest of code verified works fine.
```

Image of notification reported by PyCharm.

[image]

As suggested by `lmiguelvargasf` I did try to use different values but it did not get rid of the error.

[image]

Comment: btw, isn't it better if you move the variable before the if statement starts since you are giving the same value no matter what brach the code flows?

Comment: After posting this question I did manage to get rid of the notification by moving the line `valid_login = False` outside the `if` statement but still I would like to know why this was needed?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Yes I did do that as I noticed the redundancy after posting. That also got rid of the message but with my understanding of code this error message is still not valid so I am trying to figure out why it was existing even with the slightly redundant variable.

Comment: you can try giving two different values to this variable and see if you get the same warning.

Comment: Since you immediately re-raise the exception, it's not actually going to be used on the next line.

Comment: A local variable assignment followed immediately by an uncaught `raise` (or a `return`, or other immediate exit from the function) is indeed unused -

Comment: What's the point of setting `valid_login = False` if you're going to immediately raise an exception that exits the namespace?

Comment: @jasonharper humm. I didn't even think about that. That makes sense. I still want the function to continue after error occurs so I should probably log the the error or use a pop up message instead of doing `raise` I am guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting an error because in the `else` branch, you are raising an exception, and that variable will never be used because the flow execution terminates when the exception is raised.

Comment: Moving the variable outside of the if statement did get rid of the message but it was not due to the same variable value being set. I tested it with different values with the same notification.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, you get that warning because you are raising an error, and that means the code flow will stop, so the variable will never be used.